# Convert unicode characters in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unicode

I have the following string, I want to know how can I convert it into a regular string (it is originally contains arabic characters)?

```
\u062a\u0648\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u0634\u0645\u0627\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0632\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0632\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u062c\u0627 \u06cc
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why negative votes?!
If it is not your question or simply you do not care about the question and found it very simple, just ignore it and show a little dignity!

Comment: I assume people think you have put down too little effort. However I would guess you need to have a clue to provide example code, so you do not need to bother. I believe the question is ok, so +1 from me at least :)

Comment: Thanks partrik for your point of view. But as I commented below, there is an issue with the ASCII and Unicode documentation in MATLAB. Because sprintf documentation states that \x is supposed to specify an ascii code, but it seems that actually it supports unicode, not ascii.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an "issue". Look at it as if you do ascii and get the rest for free. What tokens would be the 127 first for any unicode encoding you think?

Comment: Patrik, I'm just referring to the Luis comment: "Yes, the documentation says ASCII but it probably should say Unicode. However, to be sure you should ask The Mathworks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `x` denotes the original string. Then you can use

```
y = char(hex2dec(strsplit(x, '\\u')).');
```

How it works:

1. `strsplit(..., '\\u')` splits the string at occurrences of `'\u'`. The result is a cell array of (sub)strings.
2. `hex2dec(...).'` interprets each string as a hexadecimal number and converts to decimal. The result is a numeric row vector.
3. `char` casts each number to a character, producing a string.

For your example string

```
x = '\u062a\u0648\u062f\u0647 \u0648 \u0634\u0645\u0627\u0631 \u0633\u0627\u0632\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0632\u0646\u062f\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u062c\u0627 \u06cc'
```

the code gives

```
y =
 تودهوشمارسازوارههایزندهدرجای
```

No idea what it means :-)

Comment: Dear Luis,
Thanks for your response, it is really helpful; but there is a question: why "x" denotes unicode and not the "u"? Is there a problem with MATLAB documentation? Since, in Python (I do not know about other languages) using simply decoding the string will work.
Also, the above could be simply done via :

sprintf(strrep(MySampleString, '\u', '\x'))

Nevertheless, the question remains the same: why x instead of u?

Best regards.

Comment: @user116704 I'm not sure what you mean. In my code `x` is just the name of the variable. As for your code, it works because `sprintf` interprets `\xN` as _character whose ASCII code is the hexadecimal number N_, according to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html), and that seems to be valid for Unicode, not just ASCII

Comment: So, there is a problem in sprintf documentation, right? because it is not ASCII for sure. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the documentation says ASCII but it probably should say Unicode. However, to be sure you should ask The Mathworks

Comment: On the other hand. using `char` as in my code you are on the safe side, because its [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) does say that it supports Unicode points up to 65535

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for helpful comments and answers.

Comment: Welcome! Glad I could help